# What is diffrence between wp_enqueue_script() and wp_register_script()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not clear when/where I will use  `wp_enqueue_script()` **or** `wp_register_script()`

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque

Answer (score 15):

In simple words;

`wp_enqueue_script` means, **Add in a queue to register the file**
`wp_register_script` means, **Register the file immediately**

> **`wp_register_script`** registers a script to be enqueued later using the **`wp_enqueue_script()`** function.
>
> **`wp_enqueue_script()`** registers the script if $src provided (does NOT overwrite), and enqueues it.
> *source*: [Developer.wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)

Here is brief [Answer on WordpressDevelopment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82492)

**wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );**

Scripts that have been pre-registered using **wp_register_script()** do not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued. WordPress will automatically include the registered script before it includes the enqueued script that lists the registered script’s handle as a dependency.

---

**wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );**

**wp_enqueue_script()** links a script file to the generated page at the right time according to the script dependencies, if the script has not been already included and if all the dependencies have been registered. You could either link a script with a handle previously registered using the wp_register_script() function, or provide this function with all the parameters necessary to link a script.

Comment: The WP people are really out of there minds! This is insanely confusing naming conventions.

Comment: Your "simple words" at the beginning of your answer are the exact opposite of what is actually correct. In fact it is the other way around:
- wp_enqueue_script means, Register the file and add the file immediately to the queue
- wp_register_script means, Only register the file but wait for enqueuing it later.

Comment: After reading the contradictions in the first two paragraph, there is more confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I have arrived here because I was having the same Q.
having read about it I think that there is still place for an updated answer so here is my attempt:

`wp_register_script` - This tells Wordpress about a script ***but is not enough to load the script***
`wp_enqueue_script` makes sure all the dependency scripts (and their dependencies recursively) will be loaded and the main script will be loaded after them.

`wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` use the same logic.

So for a script to be loaded it must either the be the "main" script in a call to `wp_enqueue_script` or be listed as a dependency in a call to `wp_enqueue_script` (And be previously either registered or enqueued as the main script)

Enqueueing of scripts **and styles** (there are no respective `*_*_styles` action hooks)  should be within

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , myFunc); // - for scripts that need to run on the front end
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', myFunc); // - for scripts that need to run on the admin panel
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', myFunc); //- for scripts that need to run on the login page
```

if a script is needed in all said situations you can register/enqueue it within the 'init' action.

Within myFunc you should make the calls to `wp_enquq_script` and `wp_enquq_style`.

myFunc can also receives a parameter ( $hook ) that can be used if you want to limit the loading of the script to a specific page within the admin dashboard.

e.g.

```
function my_enqueue_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( 'pagename.php' == $hook ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myscript.js', array(), '1.0' );
    }
    
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_admin_scripts' );
```

The global variables `$wp_scripts` and `$wp_styles` have a `registered` property listing the registered scripts and styles.

print_r(get_current_screen()) can also be helpful in limiting the context of when you are loading you scripts and styles

Comment: Most informative and specific answer! Thanks.

Comment: When you use wp_register_script, the script can be loaded automatically if another script depends on it. For example, it is very common register the library jQuery, in functions.php, instead of enqueue it, because this way the library will be loaded on demand (when another script needs it).

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding the `wp_register_scripts` and the `wp_register_scripts` are function that registers your script(js) and style (css) immediately but does not directly load them in your Wordpress pages.

There is a kind of `switch()` statement that works with these functions making them to load your "scripts" only on pages that needs them.

It is not necessary to register all your scripts but this can add some logic to your code and surely, it makes you a better developer; with a sense of clean code writing.

A good example is when enqueuing a custom stylesheet for your admin area, or a custom js script (e.g to work with the Wordpress Media Uploader). In these two scenarios you should use the `wp_register_style` and the `wp_register_script` respectively. Furthermore, in both cases you call your function at the `admin_enqueue_scripts` so a good rule of thumb is when you are hooking into the `admin_enqueue_scripts` be sure to register your script.