# WordPress Jquery Integration

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I did a jquery on jsfiddle and it works fine there but when I apply it to wordpress it doesnt seem work. I am not sure what is wrong, is there a special syntax when using js on wp?

https://jsfiddle.net/f911e0yq/9/

In WordPress (no error)

in function.php

```
function scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sizetab',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_method' );
```

in my.js file

```
(function ($) {
  $('#button').click(
    function() {
      $('.description_tab').removeClass('active');
      $('.additional_information_tab').removeClass('active');
      $('.reviews_tab').removeClass('active');
      $('.ux_global_tab_tab').addClass('active');
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Usually WordPress uses `jQuery` in lieu of `$` but more importantly, what errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: looks like all is working ok. can you provide website url where you're using it.if the file is loading in the page, then the only problem can be, which I guess: it's your button is undefined when your code starts work. you can use this: `wp_enqueue_script( 'sizetab',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my.js' , array( 'jquery' ), null, true );`. this will load your script into footer, after all content of your website

Comment: 1. Do a "View Source".  Is your script listed? (search for `my.js`).  If not, then the URL you have chosen is incorrect. 2. Have you checked your brower's developer console for errors? If not, you should learn to use it - required tool for developing javascript.  3. Do you have an element with an id of `button` on the page? If not, then that won't work.  4. **Your script is fine** - you're using it properly, it should not need any changes to run in WP.  The problem is almost 100% related to your script file not loading.

Comment: @j08691 - OP is using a no-conflict-save document ready, yes? That is injecting `jQuery` into the `$` variable, so all should work properly, yes?

Comment: it doesnt produce any error on the browser console. I am working on Lamp so I cannot give an actual url. Yes my source is listed in view source

Comment: @JeVic so, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: ill try hold on

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan thanks that works, what is the purpose of null, true?

Comment: Can you please check the view source whether the js file is loading into the page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I guessed, the issue was that your `script` loaded before your page content loading. So, `#button` tag was `undefined` for your code.

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) functions parameters are:

```
wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer)
```

`$ver` is the version of the script, which will be loaded (`http://website.com/someScript.js?ver=1.0.0`). By default, it's `false`. We used `null`, which is same in this case: not loading the script version and loading current WordPress version. `$in_footer` loads script into header or into footer of your page/website. By default, it's `false`( loading into the `<header>` tag ).

We used this code:

```
function scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sizetab', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my.js' , array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_method' );
```

and defined there, that we want to load our script into the footer of website( after all content ) with adding `null, true`( don't have version and want to load into footer ).

Answer (score 1):

There are no JavaScript errors, so you won't see anything in the console - the JavaScript code is just fine. The issue is *how you enqueued your js*. You need to move it to the footer, otherwise you'll need to rebind your event handlers because they don't exist when jQuery is defined.

If you look at the source docs for [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), you can see you've omitted the last two parameters, `$ver` and `$in_footer`. In order to set the `in_footer` variable you need a version, so you can either get fancy and use the `filemtime` functions or just set it to `''`, `'1.0'`, or `null` - and then you can set `$in_footer` to true.

```
function scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sizetab',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_method' );
```

It's generally considered a best practice to move all custom JavaScript files to the footer if you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scripts_method() {
wp_register_script( 'sizetab',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'js/my.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'sizetab' );
}
```

I use this code block to load custom .js files

Comment: Just a note: Generally speaking don't need to use `wp_register_script` if you're enqueueing the file immediately afterwards. You can simplify the code by just using `wp_enqueue_script` - If you'd like, you can read a bit more than I can explain in a comment here: [wp_register_script vs. wp_enqueue_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653993/what-is-diffrence-between-wp-enqueue-script-and-wp-register-script)